# Passing dynamic variables to a service constructor

Tags: symfony

I have a service in Symfony2 that looks like:

```
services:
    MyCustomService:
        class:     MyClass
        arguments: //Arguments aren't static, but dynamic based on application logic.
```

Is it possible to pass dynamic variables to a service's constructor?

There doesn't seem to be any extra parameters within a controller's `$this->get('MyCustomService');`

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If, for whatever reason, you are unable to configure the service after instantiation (i.e., [with a configurator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/configurators.html)). What about delegating that responsibility [to a factory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html)? It will let you instantiate services with "dynamic arguments".

```
services:
    MyCustomServiceFactory:
        class: MyClassFactory
        arguments: [ @dynamicService, %time_prefix% ]
    MyCustomService:
        class:              MyClass
        factory_service:    MyCustomServiceFactory
        factory_method:     get
```

Your factory would like something like this:

```
class MyClassFactory
{
    private $dynamicService;
    private $timePrefix;

    public function __construct(MyDynamicService $dynamicService, $timePrefix)
    {
        $this->dynamicService = $dynamicService;
        $this->timePrefix = $timePrefix;

    }

    public function get()
    {
        // Dynamic arguments based on application logic.
        $dynamicArg1 = $this->dynamicService->getArg()
        $dynamicArg2 = $this->timePrefix . time();

        return new MyClass($dynamicArg1, $dynamicArg2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't like the class having to worry about instantiating itself when a factory makes more sense. However I just initialized the factory manually, used `get($args)` and `return new MyClass($args)` in my case. Thanks!

Comment: How do you call this?

Comment: I'm also curious how this is called. How are you passing in %time_prefix% dynamically? That is still a parameter that needs to be defined in the yaml file afaik

Comment: @jimsmith, the service container calls the factory method `MyClassFactory::get` upon injecting `MyCustomService`.

Note: the [service definition yaml has changed](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html#factories-passing-arguments-factory-method) quite a bit since my original answer.

Comment: @MichaelMallett, `%time_prefix%` is not passed dynamically – those values, `$dynamicArg1`, `$dynamicArg2`, are whats computed dynamically and passed to MyClass instance in the factory getter.

Comment: Can you write an example how to use it from a controller?

Answer (score 9):

To me, it sounds like, you do not understand what a word "service" really means. What you are trying to achieve, would not be a service anymore.

You can still define a setter method inside your "MyClass" for any custom arguments, while defining some default ones, which you basically override when you use setter method.

You would use something like this:

```
$this->get('MyCustomService')->setSomething($something);
```

Comment: I've been looking for days and I can't find anywhere that really tells me what a service really means. It's incredibly frustrating. All the documentation tells me is that it is something that uses the service container, and then how to write one. No where can I find an explanation of what they are best for, everything seems to be 'hey services yeah, they're cool here's how to make one'

Comment: @MichaelMallett Does https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html help?  A reasonable definition could be "A class that may have dependent services, but no dynamic arguments".  If you do have dynamic arguments, I don't think there's any point in making it a service.  Just stick with a regular class.  It can still have a factory method.