# what is the correct way to pass not services to the constructor of a custom normalize in symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm creating my own `Normalizer`, based on the tutorial on the `Symfony` documentation page https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer/custom_normalizer.html, which I find incomplete because it tells you how to create it but not apply it, that's the first point.

Then based on my little experience in `Symfony` I'm trying to guess how to pass data to the `normalizer` to be the proper calculations, the data I'm trying to pass are not `services`, which can be a `String or a Request object`, but none of this data allows me, really I need to understand or I need to refactor to get what I want?

I put my `normalizer` code to understand well what I am looking for.

**Normalizer:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Serializer;

use App\Entity\Task;
use App\Traits\TaskControl;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class TaskNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface
{

  use TaskControl;

  private $normalizer;
  private $rangeDate;

  public function __construct(ObjectNormalizer $normalizer, $rangeDate )
  {
    $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
    $this->rangeDate  = $rangeDate;
  }


  public function normalize($task, $format = null, array $context = [])
  {
    $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($task, $format, $context);

    dd($this->rangeDate);

    $data['totalWork'] = $this->timeTask($task,$this->rangeDate);

    return $data;
  }

  public function supportsNormalization($task, $format = null, array $context = []): bool
  {
    return $task instanceof Task;
  }

}
```

**Applying the normalizer:**
Passing the variable $rangeDate that is dynamic from object Request.

```
$rangeDate   = $request->request->get('range','all');
$serializer = new Serializer([new TaskNormalizer($normalizer,$rangeDate)]);
$data = $serializer->normalize($attendances, null, ['attributes' => $attributes]);
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Serializer\TaskNormalizer": argument "$rangeDate" of method "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value explicitly.
```

Comment: Just for info, the error is coming from the fact that autowire is trying to "compile" your class into a service and has no idea what $rangeDate is.  Update the exclude section of config/services.yaml to skip over this class to make the error go away.  Of course the answer below shows you the correct way to setup a normalizer which not only makes the error go away but works as well.

Comment: And since it seems like you are using the framework then you should be aware that all you really need to do is to [inject the serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html).  No need to actually "new" one.

Comment: @Cerad I finally fixed it by passing the data through the context, which I didn't know I could do, I've already given the right answer. Thank you for the information,

Comment: I understand you have an answer.  Just wanted to be sure you knew that the answer could be refined a bit since you are using the framework.  Just inject the serializer and the normalizer will automatically be attached.  Saves you from having to create the objects yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you pass your range date as constructor argument?

Normalizer is a service dependency, rangeDate is a dynamic value.

You can pass it as an argument for the method normalize instead either as a new argument, or in the context array:

```
$rangeDate  = $request->request->get('range','all');
$serializer = new Serializer([new TaskNormalizer($normalizer)]);
$data       = $serializer->normalize($attendances, null, ['attributes' => $attributes, 'rangeDate' => $rangeDate]);
```

Comment: Of course, but what's the way to do it? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Well, just remove rangeDate it from the constructor, remove it from being a class attribute, Remo and add it as parameter in normalize method (in third for example).

```
$rangeDate   = $request->request->get('range','all');
$serializer = new Serializer([new TaskNormalizer($normalizer)]);
$data = $serializer->normalize($attendances, null, $rangeDate, ['attributes' => $attributes]);
```

Comment: Thanks I finally got it through the context: `$data = $serializer->normalize($attendances, null, ['attributes' => $attributes, 'rangeDate' => $rangeDate]);`  You edit your answer by adding this and I give it for the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have t odeclare your service explicitely... something like this should do the trick:

```
## services.yml
 App\Serializer\TaskNormalizer :
            arguments:
                $normalizer: '@serializer.normalizer.object' ## check the alias ... 
                $rangeDate: '%range_date%'
```

Keep in mind that it is better depend on interface than class, for the sake of dependency inversion principle. So you should think about changing the constructor to :

```
 ## your class
public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $normalizer, $rangeDate )
      {
        $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
        $this->rangeDate  = $rangeDate;
      }
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problema that $rangeDate is dynamic data from object Request and no static like for use the '%range_date%', I don't really find a way to pass $rangeDate = $request->request->get('range','all'); to normalize, I need to do calculations for the working time and show it serialized.

Comment: is it ? Then you should take a look at his : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811856/passing-dynamic-variables-to-a-service-constructor