# How to initialize Symfony service at runtime?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to have a service depends on some parameter, like this:

```yaml
# services.yaml
parameters:
    schemes: '%env(json:SCHEMES)%'
    default_scheme: '%env(DEFAULT_SCHEME)%'
    active_scheme: ''

services:
    App\Service\SoapClient:
        arguments:
            $scheme: '%active_scheme%'
```

And I use this service like this:

```php
class MyController extends AbstractController
{
    public function createClient(SoapClient $soapClient): JsonResponse
    {
        ...
        return $this->json([
            ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

The problem is `active_scheme` may be changed per request. So `active_scheme` may be one of `schemes` depending on request

I tried to solve it by creating event listener:

```php
final class RequestListener
{
    public function __construct(
        #[Autowire(service: 'service_container')]
        private readonly ContainerInterface $container,

        #[Autowire(param: 'kernel.environment')]
        private readonly string $env
    )
    {
    }

    #[AsEventListener(event: KernelEvents::REQUEST)]
    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $schemes = $this->container->getParameter('schemes');
        $defaultScheme = $this->container->getParameter('default_scheme');

        if ($this->env === 'prod') {
            $this->container->setParameter('active_scheme', $schemes[$defaultScheme]);
        } else {
            if (!$event->getRequest()->request->has('scheme')) {
                throw new BadRequestHttpException('...');
            }
            $this->container->setParameter('active_scheme', $event->getRequest()->request->getString('scheme'));
        }
    }
}
```

This code throws an exception: **Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag.**

I can remove my SoapClient from services and move the code from above to controller but I don't like this solution because now I need to create SoapClient instance manually.

Is there a way to keep code as clean as possible and allow to dynamically instantiate the service parameter?

Comment: Try with Service configuration. An [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23817512/3585143) and [docs here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/configurators.html).